# LinkedList generic input

Tags: c#, generics, linked-list

I wrote the folowing method :

```
// Merge two ArrayLists to the first one without duplication
public static void mergeIntoFirst(ArrayList array1, ArrayList array2)
{
    if(array1==null | array2==null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (array1 == array2)
        return; //if they are pointing to the same array, then we can exit.

    foreach (object obj in array2)
    {
        if (!array1.Contains(obj))
            array1.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

But now I want to change the my program to work with linkedList insted, 
because arraylist doesn't work well with `linq` as far as I know...

But I need the input to be generc, and work with all linked list kind, just like here the ArrayList can contains all sort of objects.
(I'm using this method twice in my code, once with array of users, and the other with array of messages sent by the users)

I thought that using `LinkedList<object>` will solve it, since anything is object (exept int, chat double itc)

but it throws a casting exeption when running...
what shoul'd I do then? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to switch to `List<T>` instead?  That's the generic replacement for `ArrayList`.  Or you could even have it work on anything that imeplements `ICollection<T>` since all you need is `Add` and `Contains`.

Comment: it is not compiling, the compiler is saying that the Type T could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of your code that should work for any `ICollection<T>` of which both `LinkedList<T>` and `List<T>` implement.  Note that you have to define the generic type on the method.

```
public static void MergeIntoFirst<T>(ICollection<T> c1, ICollection<T> c2)
{
    if(c1==null || c2==null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (c1 == c2)
        return; //if they are pointing to the same array, then we can exit.

    foreach (T item in c2)
    {
        if (!c1.Contains(item))
            c1.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this.

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> l2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };

MergeIntoFirst(l1, l2);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", l1));
// outputs: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Note that this is close to what [`Enumerable.Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) does except that it would remove duplicates that exist in both collections and produces a new collection rather than mutating the first one.

Comment: oh I see, I didn't write <T> on the function as well. Thanks! 
BTW, is it possible to still use this with `ArrayList`? (I don't need to, but it is good to know how if Sameday i will have something like this)

Comment: @Sportalcraft No this will not work with `ArrayList` and in general you should never use `ArrayList`.  It's a relic from a time before generics.